# Как вывести в Drupal 7 форму обратной связи (например, на модуле contact) на страницу?

Tags: drupal

Везде написано, как настроить эту форму и вывести её через отдельный пункт меню на отдельной сгенирированной странице, а мне нужно на одну единственную главную страницу вывести эту форму (на этой странице нет меню). Т.е. какой код нужно поставить в файл page.tpl.php для вывода этой формы?

Answer (score 1):

```
module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
print drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
```